# Running parallel functions with union all

Tags: postgresql, parallelism

I'm trying to run 3 functions at the same time using parallelism and union all. I've read that union queries are candidates for parallelism but i can't get it to work.

The query looks like this (the function is the same, but it's on a different schema, but the result is the same even on the same schema)

```sql
-- The real function is a medium size sql query with CTEs, but i get the same result with this
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn(jsonb)
 RETURNS table(
    i int
 )
 LANGUAGE sql
 PARALLEL SAFE
 SET search_path from current
AS $function$
    select 1
$function$;


select * from catalog.fn('{}')
union all
select * from customer01.fn('{}')
union all
select * from customer02.fn('{}')
```

And i'm using this setting to force parallelism (i've tried different numbers)

[image: Settings]

I get this plan

```
Gather  (cost=0.25..28.00 rows=3000 width=4) (actual time=7.320..10.669 rows=3 loops=1)
  Output: fn.i
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=388
  ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.25..28.00 rows=1500 width=4) (actual time=2.283..2.313 rows=2 loops=2)
        Buffers: shared hit=388
        Worker 0:  actual time=2.420..2.422 rows=1 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=193
        Worker 1:  actual time=2.146..2.205 rows=2 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=195
        ->  Function Scan on catalog.fn  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=2.145..2.145 rows=1 loops=1)
              Output: fn.i
              Function Call: catalog.fn('{}'::jsonb)
              Buffers: shared hit=193
              Worker 1:  actual time=2.145..2.145 rows=1 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=193
        ->  Function Scan on customer01.fn fn_1  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=2.419..2.419 rows=1 loops=1)
              Output: fn_1.i
              Function Call: customer01.fn('{}'::jsonb)
              Buffers: shared hit=193
              Worker 0:  actual time=2.419..2.419 rows=1 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=193
        ->  Function Scan on customer02.fn fn_2  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.057..0.057 rows=1 loops=1)
              Output: fn_2.i
              Function Call: fn('{}'::jsonb)
              Buffers: shared hit=2
              Worker 1:  actual time=0.057..0.057 rows=1 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=2
Query Identifier: -2124590841971516102
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=2
Planning Time: 0.174 ms
Execution Time: 10.705 ms
```

No matter what i do, i always get 2 workers only. You can see that a function gets worker 0, and the other two gets worker 1.

With a normal query i get all the workers.

```sql
select * from catalog.product
union all
select * from customer01.product
union all
select * from customer02.product

/*
Gather  (cost=0.00..44925.16 rows=610216 width=1896) (actual time=10.779..115.180 rows=610216 loops=1)
  Output: product_2....
  Workers Planned: 8
  Workers Launched: 8
  Buffers: shared hit=43781
  ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.00..44925.16 rows=76277 width=1896) (actual time=0.008..19.008 rows=76277 loops=8)
        Buffers: shared hit=43781
...
*/
```

I don't understand what costs are, but what i want to acomplish is that i get 3 workers, 1 for each function, forcing postgresql to not care about what they do. What i see is that i'm trying to do the most basic example of parallelism, because of union all the 3 functions are independent, but it's the one i just can't get it to work.

I'm using PG 14.0

Comment: Why is parallel_leader_participation off?  That seems counterproductive.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get that at the moment.

The number of workers is hard-coded as `log2(n) + 1`, where `n` is the partition count.

[There were attempts make that configurable](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/95b1dd96-8634-4545-b1de-e2ac779beb44%40www.fastmail.com) for PostgreSQL v14, but the problem where and how to specify that proved too hard.

See [this closely related question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/285038/176905) that explains more details.